# Verify injectiveness of the function $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ satisfying the following: $f(x)=2x-(f(x))^2$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Verify injectiveness of the function $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ satisfying the following:
>   $$f(x)=2x-(f(x))^2$$

I just could see that we have 2 possible values for $f(0)$: $0,-1$, nothing more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f(x)=f(y)$, then $f(x)+f(x)^2=f(y)+f(y)^2$, and hence $2x=2y$ and hence $x=y$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Just write $f(x)=f(y)$ and use the functional relation.

Answer (score 1):

$$f^2(x)+f(x)-2x=0$$
$$f(x)=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+8x}}{2}$$

Comment: So we have two possible $f$'s,and must consider each case separately

Comment: I think each $f$ function satisfy equation.

Comment: Yes,as @kimchilover proved it's injective